# Tableview Data Not Reloading After Restore Plist Data Using Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

I have created `JSON` data store into `plist` and get the plist data and load into table array then showing on table Its everything working perfectly. My problem is after some button action again I am calling JSON and store into plist then I am trying to reload `tableview` data but its not `reloading`.

`FYI:` My tableview `accordion` type and I am getting all the data from Plist, I have created by `storyboard`.

My Code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //TABLEVIEW CONTROLLER

    self.tableview.dataSource=self;
    self.tableview.delegate=self;

    NSArray *pathse = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = pathse.firstObject;
    plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dataplist.plist"];
    NSMutableDictionary *plistDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: plistPath];
    self.arrayOriginal  = [plistDic valueForKey:@"Objects"];
    NSLog(@"array = %@", self.arrayOriginal);

    self.arForTable = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self.arForTable addObjectsFromArray:self.arrayOriginal];
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you're doing in this "button action"? All we can see from this is the initial setup of the `arrForTable` NSMutableArray. Not where you're refreshing this data following the "button action".

Comment: could you show your plist data structure

Comment: the - "startLocating:" Method only I am calling from another one class Its calling also and successfully stored data but tableview not reloading ! old data only showing!Updated plz check above

Comment: [self.tableview reloadData]; just after you fetch plist data. in view did load. give a try

Comment: Its not working!@Imran

Comment: self.arForTable  may i know log of it

Comment: Now I checked that array into refresh method     NSLog(@"************** CHECKING DATA UPDATED OR NOT **************** : %@", self.arrayOriginal); Its showing old data only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100012/discussion-between-imran-and-sanju).

Comment: I am waiting on chat @Imran